# can I use MySQL service port directly with Node js?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

This is a Windows 7 OS.

Actually it is MariaDB (fork of MySQL).

The port is the default one, 3306 ... I'm just wondering: is there any way to use this "way in" to the dbase system (using JS) without setting up a Node js server (e.g. with Express)?

Of course it is possible to use node-mysql without setting up a socket, just a connection... but it just crossed my mind that there's already a port present...

Comment: If that were possible, it would be a terrible idea for security reasons.

Comment: You mean _without_ Node.js.

Comment: OK thanks - so I basically have to get to grips with Express...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser-side Javascript cannot open raw sockets.